# Find max of each column and its index with numpy (+ when max is duplicate in the same col)

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, max

I have the following 2D numpy array:

```
>>> A = ([[  100,   -5,   3, 200],
           [  20, -100,   4,   8],
           [  12,  -10,  10,   4],
           [-100,   80,   4,  14]])

>>> A = np.array(A)
```

I want to find the absolute max value of each column and its index.

For the absolute max I use:

```
>>> max_col = abs(A).max(axis=0)
>>> print(max_col)
[100 100  10 200]
```

But when it comes to finding all indices, I can't get the **[3][0]** -> **-100** index in my list.

I used:

```
>>> maxValueIndex = abs(A).argmax(axis=0)
[0 1 2 0]
```

I want my maxValueIndex to be:

```
[0 3 1 2 0]
```

Maybe I should use the **np.where()** function but I don't know how.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `numpy.where`:

```
# max_col = abs(A).max(axis=0)
np.where(abs(A) == max_col)
```

output: `(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 3, 1, 2, 0]))`

If you only want the column indices:

```
np.where(abs(A) == max_col)[1]
```

output: `array([0, 3, 1, 2, 0])`

Comment: So np.where returns a tuple because I'm refering to a 2D-array? [0] is for the rows and [1] is for the columns?

Comment: It always returns a tuple, with as many arrays as there are dimensions, in order (so 0 for the "rows" and 1 for "columns" in 2D)